# Android: can write but can't read file from Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES

Tags: android

I'm trying to save pictures on my Android phone and then restore them when it's needed.

So I use RxJava to save and read this files to `Environment.DITECTORY_PICTURES` folder. My problem is that I can write an image (my rx method calls `onNext`, but not `onError`, debug shows the correct path, settings testify that app data size grows), but can't read from there.

When I use my reading code with the correct path its throws `FileNotFoundException`. When I use this test code

```
        try {
            String path = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES;
            Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
            File directory = new File(path);
            File[] files =  directory.listFiles();
            Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
                Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

it throws NPE saying that `files` array is `null`.

I have Read/Write external storage permissions granted. Tested on Android 5 and 6, so I guess there is nothing about Runtime permissions as well.

Is there something special about reading from `Environment` folders I don't know?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` is not a fulll qualified path to the file system directory, the one you looking for is get trough the class and using this as argument.

```
File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Theres more kind of storages described at:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Comment: File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

Comment: Oh, thanks. This looks reasonable. Unfortunately I'll be able to try only in monday. Anyway I'll accept immediately after I will succeed.

Comment: You did not have to change your answer as now my remark is nonsense.